# Фильтр времени

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток. Подскажите как сделать вот такую штуку http://floomby.ru/s1/AYbVAy, это типо временного фильтра что-ли, сам не знаю, Должен работать пошагово без плавного перетаскивания, тоесть при клике полоса перемещается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь слайдером и сделайте анимацию на передвижение
    [Jq-ui Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default)

Comment: А кроме UI, нету больше??

Comment: как это нету? Можете сами написать на чистом JS
или загуглить, вот хорошая сравнительная таблица
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

как пример, слайдер на mooTools
http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Slider